# Fitting an image centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently stuck, as I'm trying to center an image in the page. Here is what I have

HTML

```
<div class="bg-container">
    <img alt="Background" class="random bgimg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bgimg{
max-height: 640px;
width: 1920px;
clip: auto;
}

.bg-container{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Note: There is no src attribute in the img tag as I use the random class to pull a random image via JavaScript.

I've tried applying center-block and text-center to both the div and image classes to no avail. Here is an example of the actual page. http://shepherdjerred.com/demo/front/

I appreciate any help given.

Comment: What do you mean? I see it centered, at least horizontaly. Verticaly it seems a bit off because of the fixed top navbar

Comment: Sorry, I should of added, it centers fine on widths of 1080px, however anything smaller it doesn't.

Comment: You can also try to add it as a centered CSS background, that should make no problem then.

Comment: Do not omit the src of the image. Use javascript to update the src. Otherwise do not use an img element but a div. It has no sense to add a background image to an img element. You do not set background as an alternative text.

Comment: Sorry for my imprecise comment, that's what I have thought, to restructure it as a div with required height and centered CSS background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not add px unit in width attribute of an image element.
2. To center the image,add this to your selector

   ```
   .bgimg {
     display: block;
     margin: auto;
   }
   ```